Nginx serve 2 service first as default path and second as path
I started learning NGINX and I have an NGINX server and my goal is to serve 2 app in it, one is frontend and the other is backend. since I should configure SSL too, want to use backend as sub path. by default if user asks for example.com we will show frontend and if user asks for example.com/backend we will return backend. here is my configuration:
worker_processes 1;
events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:5000;
    }
    upstream backend {
        server backend:5001;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass              http://frontend;
        }
        location /backend/ {
            proxy_pass              http://backend;
        }
    }
}

when I input example.com, I'm getting result from frontend, but when I input example.com/backend it return 404 not found. how can I fix it?
